# Convert JSON to vertical table

Tags: json, bash, width, jq, tabular-form

I have the below payload, and what I am trying to produce is a horizontal column output like such, with a newline between entries. Does someone know how this can be achieved? Either in jq directly or with some interesting bash. :

```
StackId              : arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983
EventId              : 97b2fbf0-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983
StackName            : cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda
LogicalResourceId    : cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda
PhysicalResourceId   : arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983
ResourceType         : AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
Timestamp            : 2020-04-03T12:06:47.501Z
ResourceStatus       : CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
ResourceStatusReason : User Initiated

EventId              : BBPassword-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-04-03T12:06:51.336Z
StackName            : cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda
LogicalResourceId    : BBPassword
PhysicalResourceId   : 
ResourceType         : AWS::SSM::Parameter
Timestamp            : 2020-04-03T12:06:51.336Z
ResourceStatus       : CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
```

Here is the 2 commands  I am using to produce output but neither is ideal.

- I have deleted a key that's usually filled with JSON and it just messes everything up.
- The first example I insert a delimiter that I am hoping I can use later to strip out
- The second example gives me an error `xargs: unterminated quote`:
- In both cases I hardcoded the format length. But for the curious, it can be done as such: `jq -re '.StackEvents | map(to_entries | map(.key | length) |  max) | max'`

```
jq -re '.StackEvents | .[] | del(.ResourceProperties) | . * {"entry":"---"} | to_entries | .[] | "\(.key) \"\(.value?)\""' bin/logs/3.json  | xargs -n 2 printf "%-21s: %s\n"

jq -re '.StackEvents | .[] | del(.ResourceProperties) | . * {"":"\n"} | to_entries | .[] | "\(.key) \"\(.value?)\""' bin/logs/3.json  | xargs -n 2 printf "%-21s: %s\n"
```

Here is the payload:

```
{
    "StackEvents": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "EventId": "BBWebhookLogGroup-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-04-03T12:06:51.884Z",
            "StackName": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "LogicalResourceId": "BBWebhookLogGroup",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T12:06:51.884Z",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"RetentionInDays\":\"7\",\"LogGroupName\":\"cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda\"}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "EventId": "BBUserName-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-04-03T12:06:51.509Z",
            "StackName": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "LogicalResourceId": "BBUserName",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
            "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T12:06:51.509Z",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Description\":\"The username for this lambda to operate under\",\"Value\":\"chb0bitbucket\",\"Name\":\"/bb-webhooks/authorization/username\"}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "EventId": "BBWebhookLogGroup-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-04-03T12:06:51.409Z",
            "StackName": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "LogicalResourceId": "BBWebhookLogGroup",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T12:06:51.409Z",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"RetentionInDays\":\"7\",\"LogGroupName\":\"cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda\"}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "EventId": "BBPassword-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2020-04-03T12:06:51.336Z",
            "StackName": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "LogicalResourceId": "BBPassword",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
            "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T12:06:51.336Z",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Description\":\"The password for this lambda to operate under with BB. Unfortunately, using an encrypted password is currently not possible\",\"Value\":\"****\",\"Name\":\"/bb-webhooks/authorization/password\"}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "EventId": "97b2fbf0-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "StackName": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "LogicalResourceId": "cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-04-03T12:06:47.501Z",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "User Initiated"
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on input from others, I have put together a simple bash script illustrating a tiny anomaly (the column width isn't uniform):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -o pipefail

fileCount=$(( $( ls -1 logs/*.json | wc -l) - 1))
for i in $(seq 1 $fileCount); do
    jq -rs '
      def width:      map(keys_unsorted | map(length) | max) | max ;
      def pad($w):    . + (($w-length)*" ") ;

      .[1].StackEvents - .[0].StackEvents | sort_by (.Timestamp) 
      | width as $w | map(to_entries | map("\(.key|pad($w)) : \(.value)"), [""]) 
      | .[][]
    ' "logs/$((i - 1)).json" "logs/$i.json"

done
```

Yields:

```
StackId              : arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983
EventId              : ApiKey-CREATE_COMPLETE-2020-04-03T12:07:47.382Z
StackName            : cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda
LogicalResourceId    : ApiKey
PhysicalResourceId   : KYgzCNAzPw5Tsy3dKBdoTaHlxywijTSrb1d2UIQ2
ResourceType         : AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
Timestamp            : 2020-04-03T12:07:47.382Z
ResourceStatus       : CREATE_COMPLETE
ResourceProperties   : {"StageKeys":[{"StageName":"beta","RestApiId":"8n6tijwaib"}]}

StackId            : arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983
EventId            : bc9371c0-75a3-11ea-b442-1217092af407
StackName          : cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda
LogicalResourceId  : cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda
PhysicalResourceId : arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:882038671278:stack/cbongiorno-30800-bb-lambda/97b14e40-75a3-11ea-bb77-0e8a861a6983
ResourceType       : AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
Timestamp          : 2020-04-03T12:07:49.203Z
ResourceStatus     : CREATE_COMPLETE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with some helper functions that can be generalized for other uses.

```
def width:      map(keys | map(length) | max) | max ;
def pad($w):    . + (($w-length)*" ") ;

  .StackEvents
| width as $w
| map(del(.ResourceProperties) | to_entries | map("\(.key|pad($w)) : \(.value)"), [""])
| .[][]
```

It should produce the desired output if jq is passed `-r`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VZdb9owFH3nV1hWH2AjkACFNHvqB6sqbR0CukorVeUkBjKCndlOGWv729m1IW3X0o12Y2ul5QGc2Ofe4@vjo/v5y2wW0j6aRKEaesg8Y5LkR3Qq0aUZxpQN1LBg3r4u/tCbnEYlJMxvTAoGV0KvUR7erMX6VxjhAqzLwVRHkWDUPKdMydzlPBciEm1McvMUIY3zpTaVPBUBbQmeUKEiKnUyxc8AJuBtQQf38iVgd7nIXUAegi/nJE5pAReK6ATj0wLELZ2cnpzOZhc5TQ7fYoA9dJJDi@fienSz7CCEJZgI5pGJ9IKYp2GfizFREWdeKi1KpLIcz3UrdtWtN5xKw/WkBpYDn7NBxAXjVtV2bdvyfSsmYz8k5a2G79RozbYam6RqOQ4lMNloWDZ1iVt3SH3LreLij2wM3zmbnZ1j6g85H73jg33B08TabTe3u82zg8OzVvvDfrvZ6VgVu2Jbds2yq12n4tl1b9MpuW7t0924ZpeHZEx15Ic534VB6iggcXZODxC7i2oNp/I@bPWsGa47TQzf7eOO50EyaX6XpuxGYwoHMk70@lWLkuWB4qhUiwTfr/DPMW0QBmcamX1HgaBGNuiARSoiioYPhbhRvQ5w0YMJBacP2AO2R6ayh70ebvRwsYezbesTNJ8fLmYPX@HrfFfFFyj7I0mF3uiqet@0t9as94zRakJfSc6dznvPaxEBURUVj5bzsj3/jpzvaVGTNUrrgBOzgVHhHpWBiBKtDjPVHVKUQmkYbAKBcJAaRhLNKwsujnRIuAAoZSEVJsJH7dlzAQ9924@UnwYjqszctbbLcDyTucPIMknVkIvom9FkOcv28kX@RG@vrV3rT/L2v@HgtXVL/r/9GgG0iJQTLsJVJVmt1tcsyYzR87HfZXv@J/abLErzS/uFFhw68J2dEjpisFalDKbiaREMHOIjwhBlgZgm0K/cBIVwQSoEiCOeIsYVSriUkR/TO2b@Cp6VPTyL/tJvCsArfb//KPifvBerw5ffk2dQzaVXc1fzeXvNxzM1e9wNrTWgQXLW2u/rlvBWi38jZDM6zV3NLPEd)

EDIT: as [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) and [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) point out in the comments this solution could be improved using `keys_unsorted` and should exclude `.ResourceProperties` from the width calculation.
Here is version with those improvements:

```
def width:      map(keys_unsorted | map(length) | max) | max ;
def pad($w):    . + (($w-length)*" ") ;

  .StackEvents
| map(del(.ResourceProperties))
| width as $w
| map(to_entries | map("\(.key|pad($w)) : \(.value)"), [""])
| .[][]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vffb9owEH7nr7CsPsBGIAEKafbUX6uQtg4BXaVBVTmJW7IGO7OdMtb2b2dnQ2jXwka7sbXS8gDBd/fd5/N3J/P5y2QS0jM0ikI18JB5hiTJX9CxPE2Z5ELREF2btZiyczUomF9fZ1/oTU6HJyTMb4wKBqCEXqM8/LJm/q8wwgXwy4Gpo0hwsX9JmZK5KWhI43ypTSVPRUBbgidUqIjKQgHshhQiEm2MZt6Kn0KsAIcZJ9zPl4Dr9YxAAXkIVi5JnNICLhRRD@MTDVXqnfROJpOrnGaI79DAHurl0Oy5mr/dujVDcMFEMI@MpBfEPA3PuBgSFXHmpdKiRCrL8Vy3YlfdesOpNFxP6sBy4HN2HnHBuFW1Xdu2fN@KydAPSXmr4Ts1WrOtxiapWo5DCRgbDcumLnHrDqlvuVVc/JGN4Ttls7NzTP0B5xfv@PmB4Gli7bb3t7v7p83D01b7w0F7v9OxKnbFtuyaZVe7TsWz696mU3Ld2qf7uGaXh2RINfJyzvfDIHUUkDg7uiXE7ke1BmP5MGz1rFlcd5wYvtvHHc@DZNJ8LkzZjYYUDmSYaP9Vi5LlgeKoVIsEP6zwz2PaIAzOdGS2jgJBjWxQk0UqItBZyyBuG0EDXPXBoOD0IbbJ9shY9rHXx40@LvZxtm19gmZ5eTH7@AbP890UX6DsjyQVeqOr6n3T3lqz3jNGqwl9JTl3Ou89r0UEoCoqHi3nRXv@HTk/0KIma5TWgUnMzo0K96gMRJRodRhTd0BRCqVhsAkEwkFqEEk0rSxSHGlIaACUspAKg/BRz@ypgAe@7UfKT4MLqoxtru0yHM9oOmFkmaRqwEX0zWiynGV7@SJ/4myvrV3rT5rtf2OC19Yt@f/j1wigRaQccRGuKslqtb5mSWaMns/4XbTnfzJ@k1lpfjl@4Z4N1@ydnRI6YuCrUgameFyEAQ74iDBEWSDGif4nMAcFuCAVAsQRjxHjCiVcysiP6b1h/gqelWd4hv7SOwXCK2f@2aPC/2RfrB6@uE@eQTUXtuau5vN2zsczNXtch9YacEFy1nrf11fCO1f8WyGbt5PczcQS3wE)

Comment: `keys_unsorted` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: See also @oguzismail's remark about excluding ResourceProperties from the computation of the width.

Comment: Deleted the comment without seeing this, sorry. But it was *If ResourceProperties is to be deleted, why is it taken into consideration in calculation of the max width?*

Comment: Actually this works well enough to re-include it. However, I am streaming content and the formatting is wrong. I will update the question with a script to demonstrate. It's minor.

Answer (score 2):

JQ doesn't have a builtin for padding strings but it's not that hard to implement that functionality. Given `-r/--raw-output` option on the command line, below script will produce your desired output.

```
.StackEvents
| map(del(.ResourceProperties))
| ( [ .[] | keys_unsorted[] ]
    | map(length)
    | max + 1
  ) as $max
| .[]
  | ( keys_unsorted as $keys
    | [ $keys,
      ( $keys
        | map(length)
        | map($max - .)
        | map(. * " " + ": ")
      ),
      map(.)
    ]
    | transpose[]
    | add
  ),
  ""
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OlagrvZGwI)</sup>

Comment: This is quite brilliant actually, seeing this I actually missed the req. to add new lines between the records

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that:

- uses max/1 for efficiency
- addresses some of the issues with
  calculating the "width" of Unicode strings, e.g. if we want the
  "width" of:

  `"J̲o̲s̲é̲"` to be calculated as 4

Note that the jq filter `grapheme_length` as defined here ignores
issues with control characters and zero-width spaces.

#### Generic functions

```
def max(stream):
  reduce stream as $x (null; if . == null then $x elif $x > . then $x else . end);

# Grapheme Length ignoring issues with control characters
# Mn = non-spacing mark
# Mc = combining
# Cf = soft-hyphen, bidi control characters, and language tag characters
def grapheme_length:
  gsub("\\p{Mn}";"") | gsub("\\p{Mc}";"") | gsub("\\p{Cf}";"")
  | length;

def pad($w): tostring + (($w - grapheme_length)*" ") ;
```

#### Main program

```
.StackEvents
| max(.[]
      | keys_unsorted[] 
      | select(. != "ResourceProperties") 
      | grapheme_length) as $w
| map(del(.ResourceProperties)
      | to_entries
      | map("\(.key|pad($w)) : \(.value)"), [""])
| .[][]
```

Comment: @oguzismail - Corrected. Tx.